# How to convert ISO 4217 code to currency code in swift

Tags: ios, currency

Is there any way to convert ISO 4217 numeric code to currency code like this:

978 -> EUR

I checked Apple docs and I found only how can I take EUR

Here is what I searched:

[Locale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale)

[Locale spesific](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1410448-availablelocaleidentifiers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API available in iOS (or any other Apple OS) that provides information about ISO 4217 codes. You will need to create your own mapping.

I would find a definitive list of codes (perhaps Wikipedia or the ISO website) and put the codes in a plist file. Then write a simple `Locale` extension that lets you get a currency code from a 4217 code.

Comment: Is this answer still valid? How about swift 5? does it contain something similar at least?

Answer (score 3):

As rmaddy suggested I made a plist with iso4217 codes and did my own mapping, here is the [playground](https://github.com/mvorisis/ISO-4217-codes) for anyone who wants it.